# How to use the Volley Library to parse a JSON array?

Tags: android, json, rest, android-volley

Here is the json: https://api.jamendo.com/v3.0/tracks/?client_id=70c68f47&format=jsonpretty&limit=200&search=disco

My question is how to make parsing method correct with this solution what I have. I don't have any additional rest adapter, volley should get JSON from this API.

Anybody will help me to remake first code, to work with this API?

Here is request what I am trying to change for parsing this API:

```
JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();


                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("results");
                            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < jsonArray.length(); i2++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject3 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i2);
                                DataModelList movie = new DataModelList();
                                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("name"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("id"))
                                        .doubleValue());
                                movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releasedate"));
                                movieList.add(movie);
                            }



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
```

Data Model:

```
public class DataModelList {
private String title, thumbnailUrl;
private int year;
private double rating;
private ArrayList<String> genre;

public DataModelList() {
}

public DataModelList(String name, String thumbnailUrl, int year, double rating,
             ArrayList<String> genre) {
    this.title = name;
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    this.year = year;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.genre = genre;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String name) {
    this.title = name;
}

public String getThumbnailUrl() {
    return thumbnailUrl;
}

public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public double getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public void setRating(double rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}

}
```

Adapter List:

```
public class AdapterDataList extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<DataModelList> movieItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = ControllerSingleton.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public AdapterDataList(Activity activity, List<DataModelList> movieItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return movieItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = ControllerSingleton.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
    TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
    TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

    // getting movie data for the row
    DataModelList m = movieItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

    // title
    title.setText(m.getTitle());

    // rating
    rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

    // genre


    // release year
    year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

    return convertView;
}

}
```

Overall Fragment where I want to parse this JSON:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment{
private static final String TAG = "log";
private static final String url = "https://api.jamendo.com/v3.0/tracks/?client_id=70c68f47&format=jsonpretty&limit=200&search=disco";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<DataModelList> movieList = new ArrayList<DataModelList>();
private ListView listView;
private AdapterDataList adapter;
public FirstFragment() {


}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);

    adapter = new AdapterDataList(getActivity(),movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();


                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("results");
                            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < jsonArray.length(); i2++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject3 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i2);
                                DataModelList movie = new DataModelList();
                                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("name"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("id"))
                                        .doubleValue());
                                movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releasedate"));
                                movieList.add(movie);
                            }



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    ControllerSingleton.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

}


private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Do you have anything against using Gson and/or Retrofit?

Comment: Have you good tutorial to populate NAMED jsonarray into listview?
btw. is gson have image loader like volley? First time (5 years with android o_O) I am trying to retrive json from some API. Previously I was using old json parser with httpget but its dinosaur.

Comment: you can just use Gson for the parsing , it has saved me from writing alot of code.

Comment: Any tutorial you find will be fine. If not, find another one. Gson is only for the JSON parsing to Java classes. And JSON doesn't have named arrays, so not sure what you mean by that. You can use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate a Java class from your JSON.

Comment: Yes, I know pojo schema site, good advice. BTW. I found a good gson tutorial, what exactly I need. https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

but question is how to load images then into ImageView and not get some outofmemory? Volley library done it for me.

Comment: http://codex2android.blogspot.in/2015/11/adding-json-array-to-serializable-class.html, this will give you an idea.

Comment: I made it with retrofit and universal image loader ;) but thx

Answer (score 0):

Solved with Retrofit and Universal Image Loader.

Comment: To mark this question as solved, please tick the tick icon to the left of this answer, thanks. It is ideal if you can add more detail too - this is rather brief for an answer here.